Seperated Gitlab Pages Server Configuration
Whatever I did, I could not find the right solution for enabling gitlab pages on separate server.
My gitlab version is that 15.11.13
Assume that,
main gitlab server : app1
gitlab pages server : app2
So on the app1,
I have gitlab.rb configuration like that ,
external_url 'https://test-gitlab.echo.com'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/star_echo_com.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/star_echo_com.key"

#pages
pages_external_url "http://pages.test-gitlab.echo.com"
gitlab_pages['enable'] = false
pages_nginx['enable'] = false

and also on the app2 ,
roles ['pages_role']
pages_external_url "http://pages.test-gitlab.echo.com"

gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
gitlab_pages['namespace_in_path'] = true  # Forces path-based URLs instead of subdomains
gitlab_pages['enable_disk'] = true
gitlab_rails['pages_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/pages"

So that, there is also an nginx server which is for domain redirects.
After setting the gitlab pages enable, I am making a test deploy under the /public to check is that works or not.
So that, there is nothing on the page. For ex, I am going to deploy basic " hello world."
however I cannot see anything at the /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/pages under the app2 . Nothing has been created even a single file.
What am I missing, what is the problem ?
Hint : I was following that documentation https://archives.docs.gitlab.com/15.11/ee/administration/pages/
Running gitlab pages on a separated server
